# Flutter In App Purchases Consumable Product - Purchase Stream not firing

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, in-app-purchase

I am using in_app_purchases flutter package to handle my in app purchasing needs on both android and ios. I only use consumable IAP. But my purchase stream is not firing. Only the queryPastPurchases method returns the list of the consumable. So Im bit confused with the plugin. I have also started to listen to the purchasestream as soon as the app starts in the main method. However Im not receiving the purchase updates in the Purchase Stream.

Also this statement from the in_app_purchase seems a bit ambigous it says trying to complete a pending purchase can cause a error. However it is mentioned to retry the purchase completion on pending status

```
Completing a [PurchaseStatus.pending] purchase will cause an exception.
For convenience, [PurchaseDetails.pendingCompletePurchase] indicates if a 
purchase is pending for completion.

The method returns a [BillingResultWrapper] to indicate a detailed status 
of the complete process.
If the result contains [BillingResponse.error] or 
[BillingResponse.serviceUnavailable], the developer should try
to complete the purchase via this method again, or retry the 
[completePurchase] it at a later time.
If the result indicates other errors, there might be some issue with
the app's code. The developer is responsible to fix the issue.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at my answer here:
[How can I dd in-app-purchase functionality to my flutter app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63985943/how-can-i-dd-in-app-purchase-functionality-to-my-flutter-app/65976171#65976171)

I've also added some links to a video tutorial, which will help you.
Please use the **flutter_in_app_purchase** package. It's a fork of the original **in_app_purchase** package